# PrestaShop AdminController - is there better way to preserve backslashes and html entites?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm creatin a Prestashop module for my e-store; I've created module's own `AdminController`-inheritor class with standart List and Form views to manage module settings, and the `ObjectModel`-inheritor class to store setings in DB. All works good until I have to store text fields with folowing symbols: `\ < >`

The problem is that `HelperForm` **spoiles** the clean data retrieved from DB by using `Tools::getValue()` that applies stripslashes, without adding slashes to clean data.

I temporary solved problem with following:

- to save `< >` symbols I just use `self::TYPE_HTML` definition in my `ObjectModel`; This is good declarative solution (I just define field options, and controller does everything the way I need);
- but to save backslashes I have to use such interception:

.

```
public function getFieldValuePreserveSlashes($obj, $key, $id_lang = null) {
    if ($id_lang) 
        $default_value = (isset($obj->id) && $obj->id && isset($obj->{$key}[$id_lang])) ? $obj->{$key}[$id_lang] : false;
    else 
        $default_value = isset($obj->{$key}) ? $obj->{$key} : false;
    $default_value = addslashes($default_value);
    Tools::mapValue($key, 'addslashes');
    return Tools::getValue($key.($id_lang ? '_'.$id_lang : ''), $default_value);
}
public function getFieldValue($obj, $key, $id_lang = null) {
    if($key === 'export_params_text') 
        return $this->getFieldValuePreserveSlashes($obj, $key, $id_lang);
    else
        return parent::getFieldValue($obj, $key, $id_lang);
}
```

It works but I guess it is not the best way (I still hope there is some more native way, something like some options that I could set and not to duplicate core-functions code just to add 2 strings :)

PS I didnt forget about this after I solved a local task because I have such problem often enough, and if I dont want to use global override to place desired logic ther, I have to copy-paste this code from one controller to another, and this dont let me sleep calmly :)

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This question should probably belong to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You already has maybe the best solution ;)

Comment: @PixelWeb well.... its sad if so... indeed, PrestaShop frustrates me more and more because of such customization limitations... 80% of my custom functionality code - is the copy-pasted original core code that can't be reused because I just cant apply a tiny change to logic by writing tiny hook/override or setting some parameters to alter behaviour... it's almost always about copy-pasting 100 lines for the sake of changing a couple of them... sorry for offtop, but it's my very pain for now :)))

Comment: @Brewal I dont think so, tha question is not about "how good my code is", but its about "is there a methods/parameters in PrestaShop that allows solve my task without reinventing the wheel". In other words, this is engine-specific functionality question.